# Algorithm to find critical points of function of two variables

Tags: calculus

Given any function of $2$ variables such as $f=2x^2+3y^3$, would the following be the step by step method to find its critical points?

1. Differentiate it with respect to  $x$ (calling this $f_x$)
2. Differentiate it with respect to $y$ (calling this $f_y$)
3. Solve $f_x=0$ and $f_y=0$
4. Differentiate $f_x$ with respect to $x$ $(f_{xx})$
5. Differentiate $f_y$ with respect to $y$ $(f_{yy})$
6. Differentiate either $f_x$ with respect to $y$ or  $f_y$ with respect to $x$  ( the result should be the same i.e $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$)
7. Create a $2\times 2$ matrix as $$\begin{pmatrix} f_{xx}&f_{xy}\\ f_{yx} &f_{yy}\end{pmatrix}$$ substituting for every point possible found in step 3.
8. Find the determinant for the matrix.
9. If the determinant is $>0$ then this is a maximum, if it is $< 0$ it is a minimum.

Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is right except for step 9.  If the determinant is positive and $f_{xx} > 0$, the critical point is a maximum.  If the determinant is positive and $f_{xx} < 0$, the critical point is a minimum.  If the determinant is negative, the critical point is a saddle point.

Comment: what if the determinant is 0?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang It is a saddle point if determinant is $0$.

Comment: @SahibaArora What you said is either tautologically true ( = you adopt the questionable definition of a "saddle point" being a point where the gradient is $0$ and the hessian matrix is neither positive nor negative definite) or false (for instance, *the* minimum of $f(x,y)=x^4+y^4$ is in a point where $Hf(\overline p)=0$).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Step 9 is incorrect. The sensible condition to look at in order to decide whether a critical point $\overline p$ of $f\in C^2(\Bbb R^2)$ is a local maximum, a local minimum or neither is *positive/negative definiteness* of the hessian matrix $H f(\overline p)$, not the sign of $\det H f(\overline p)$.

> Specifically, if $f\in C^2(\Bbb R^n)$ and $\nabla f(\overline p)=0$, there is this second-order quasi-criterion:
>
> 1. if $Hf(\overline p)$ is positive definite, then $\overline p$ is a local minimum
> 2. if $Hf(\overline p)$ is negative definite, then $\overline p$ is a local maximum
> 3. if $Hf(\overline p)$ has both a negative and a positive signatue, then $\overline p$ is a saddle point
> 4. if $\overline p$ is a local minimum, then $Hf(\overline p)$ is positive semidefinite
> 5. if $\overline p$ is a local maximum, then $Hf(\overline p)$ is negative semidefinite

In general, when $Hf(\overline p)$ is just semidefinite (or even the zero matrix), $\overline p$ could possibly be a local minimum, a local maximum or a saddle point.

Under the additional hypothesis that $\det Hf(\overline p)\ne 0$, the semi-definiteness in point (4) and (5) collapses to definiteness, thus providing a full-fledged criterion for this special case:

> If $f\in C^2(\Bbb R^n)$, $\nabla f(\overline p)=0$ and $\det Hf(\overline p)\ne0$, then
>
> a. $\overline p$ is a local minimum if and only if $Hf(\overline p)$ is negative definite
>
> b. $\overline p$ is a local maximum if and only if $Hf(\overline p)$ is positive definite
>
> c. $\overline p$ is a saddle point if and only if the signature of $Hf(\overline p)$ is $(s,t)$ for $s,t>0$.

Due to "negative numbers counting", a non-singular $2\times 2$ symmetric real matrix falls into case (c) if and only if $\det A<0$ (and, in fact, a $2\times 2$ matrix which falls into case (3) is non-singular). This means that in the case $n=2$ the sign of the determinant of $Hf(\overline p)$ never distiguishes a local maximum from a local minimum.

**Added:** As it has already been noticed, for $2\times 2$ real matrices [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) trivializes to: a symmetric $2\times 2$ matrix with positive determinant is positive definite if and only if $\operatorname{tr}A>0$ (it can be substituted with "$A_{11}>0$", or "$A_{22}>0$"); it is negative definite if and only if $\operatorname{tr}A<0$ (it can be substituted with "$A_{11}<0$", or "$A_{22}<0$").